# can I attach event listeners to canvas events?

Tags: javascript, canvas, event-handling

I'd like to know if it's possible that if there is a canvas tag in the html I'd like to attach an event listener to it so that each time it's programmed to draw something the callback function would do something like increment a value or something

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1903884&seqNum=6

Comment: yeah but I'm not looking for mouse events I'm looking for things like fill() when the canvas has been programmed to draw something. what would the event be called?

Answer (score 0):

ah I found it! what I needed was a mutationobserver and then going through the addednodes list that it returns to search for the canvas node fyi for anyone in the future here is the resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Wow what ??? MutationObservers see the changes in DOM. Your question is about CanvasContext2D drawing updates, DOM is not implied here. You won't have anything with MO, which btw are powerfull but really consumptive, be carefull with those. What you need is just to call the callback in your drawing functions.